# Passing control object to method

Tags: axapta, ax, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm developing in Ax 2012.  I have stringEdit controls on a form which holds the same type of information and share an EDT.  I do validation on the EDT in a class.
I call the class from a check method on the form.  I use the same method on the form for all the stringEdit controls that needs this validation.  I kick of the check method on the form from the validate method of each control.

My question:  how do I pass the control that has been modified (and needs validation) to the check method?
My check method on the form looks like this:

```
public void checkNumber(FormStringControl _cntrl)
{
        MyValidationClass     valClass = new MyValidationClass(); 
    ;

    if(!valClass.validateNumber(_cntrl.text()))
    {
        _cntrl.text("");     
    }
}
```

***the problem I have is passing the current control to the above method

The validate method on the control looks like this:

```
public boolean validate()
{
    boolean ret;
    //ret = super();
    ret = element.checkNumber(this);
    return ret;
}
```

The problem I have is passing the current control I am modifying to the checkNumber method.  If I cannot pass “this” to the check method, what then should I be passing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fine to pass `this`, but you should call also `super()`:

```
public boolean validate()
{
    return super() && element.checkNumber(this);
}
```

Or:

```
public boolean validate()
{
    return super() && new MyValidationClass.validateNumber(this.text());
}
```

Consider using a static method instead (on the controlling table): `MyTable::validateNumber(this.text())`

Consider using the [validateField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xrecord.validatefield.aspx) on the table instead:

```
public boolean validateField(fieldIdToCheck)
{
    boolean ret = super(fieldIdToCheck);
    switch (fieldIdToCheck)
    {
        case fieldNum(Table,Field):
            ret = MyValidationClass::validateNumber(table.Field) && ret;
            break;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Then you do not have to make changes in the forms and you can use auto groups.

Comment: Thansk Jan.  When I initially passed "this" to the checkNumber method from the validate on the control I got an "incompatible with required type" error.  However, when I used the code you suggested "ret = super() && element.checkNumber....."  only then did it recognise that the types where the same.  It did not recognise the "this" object as the same type, but now it does.  I wonder if the super call before the call to the check method has anything to do with it?  Anyway, thanks for for your answer.

Comment: The documentation does not state explicitly but often super() does real work. Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa876155(v=ax.10).aspx